# How can I give links in pdf for a page, which is in collapsible div

Tags: html, asp.net

I want to give a link in pdf, of a page which is under collapsible div. Please see the code

```
<div class="pdfGrp" id="Nomination">        
                          <div class="pdfHd">Nomination Forms</div>
                            <div class="pdfName"><a onclick="MM_openBrWindow('pdfs/loans/Form_DA1.pdf')" style="cursor: pointer;">Form DA 1</a></div>
                            <div class="pdfName"><a onclick="MM_openBrWindow('pdfs/loans/Form_DA2.pdf')" style="cursor: pointer;">Form DA 2</a></div>
                            <div class="pdfName"><a onclick="MM_openBrWindow('pdfs/loans/Form_DA3.pdf')" style="cursor: pointer;">Form DA 3</a></div>
</div>
```

Please help

Comment: guys any one with this issue with any idea.

Comment: Actually, there's no question here, only a requirement. Can you describe what is your question? what do you expect? what do you observe? What did you tried to workaround the issue?

Comment: I want a particular div to be opened, and that div is under collapsible div. The link is given in a PDF file.

Comment: You still have no question is your comment. Can you ask a question please?